# I need to perform count between 2 tables

Tags: sql, count

i need to perform a command that would show where in the table "Ismatuota tarša" column Dalelės_kiekis is more then table "Taršos norma" column Ribinė_valandos. Anyone has idea how to do it ? Its like i have many measures of pollution, Dalelės kiekis is the amount of any pollution and Ribinė valandos is a norm for that? Please help.

Comment: How far have you got already? Have you got a query that you think should work, but isn't?

Comment: can you show the table structure?

Comment: What is your column that allows linking rows between tables

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM "Ismatuota tarša"
GROUP BY Dalelės_kiekis
HAVING count(Dalelės_kiekis) >
(SELECT count(Ribinė_valandos) from "Taršos norma")
```